# Play Framework 2.x access variable in parent layout

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Below is a simple main.scala.html template.

```html
@import services.UserProvider
@(userProvider: UserProvider)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="@lang().code()">
    <head>
    </head>

    @defining(userProvider.getUser(session())) { user =>
    <body>
        <main id="main-container">
            <div class="content">
                @content
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
    }
</html>
```

I have defined a user variable using @defining. In all of my child templates that inherit from main.scala.html, is there any way to access this "user" variable without having to make the same @defining(userProvider.getUser(session()))) call repeatedly (as shown in the child template below)?

```html
@import services.UserProvider
@(userProvider: UserProvider, model: MyModel)

@main(userProvider, model) {

    @defining(userProvider.getUser(session())) { user =>

        <div class="block-content">
            @views.html.foo.list._filter(user, model)
        </div>

        <div>
            @_showingBarPartial(user, model)
            @views.html.foo.list._table(model, user)
        </div>
    }

}
```

I have this code snippet all over my project and I am trying to determine if this is necessary and/or if it could lead to problems. It seems like, I have already defined it once in the main (parent) template, why not just reuse it instead of having to reget it in child templates.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you consider using a scala `implicit`?

from you controller you could define

`implicit val user: User = userProvider.getUser(session())`

and then in each template you would reference the implicit from the parent closure, the trick is that you have to pass reference to the implicit through each template:

**main.scala.html**

```
@(model: MyModel)(implicit val user: User)

@main(userProvider, model) {
  <div class="block-content">
    @views.html.foo(model)
    ...
```

**foo.scala.html**

```
@(model: MyModel)(implicit val user: User)

  @user.name is logged in  @* <--- using the implicit in a child template *@
```

Comment: Possibly. I am trying to understand the concept. If I declare (implicit fooTitle: String) in my main.scala.html, then I must pass in a value for fooTitle in my Java controller method that renders this view. Each subsequent view that uses main as a parent must now have (implicit fooTitle: String) declared in it in order to use @fooTitle. I just tested that this works. I am not sure I am gaining anything though, because I could just do away with implicit and pass fooTitle into each child view, for example when I render in main... @views.html.employee.list._table(model, fooTitle).

Comment: I appreciate your response and offering suggestions. I will think more about this as a solution. If I make my original example, "user," as an implicit, I still need to get "user" in my Java server code and pass that into my render method for my view that uses my main.scala.html view. If I still have to pass it in, and I still need to add references to each child view template, I guess right now I am not seeing what implicit is doing for me that I could not do by just passing in the "user" object without implicit. You have made me think of a solution in a different way though, so thank you.

Comment: with implicits you don't have to explicitly pass the `user` to each template. also something to consider, in your controller you could define an implicit method `implicit def getUser: User = userProvider.getSession()` then you also wouldn't have to define the implicit user in the controller method -- but then you'd have to determine the best way to provide the `userProvider` in scope. Glad I helped in some way, good luck

Comment: the best approach is probably to use a play action builder to modify the request to provide the user, something like this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActionsComposition#authentication

Comment: I am using the implicit approach to resolve my problem. It is like dependency injection for views. I could continue to pass variables from one view into another, but I like what the implicit approach. I have created a view model object that contains user specific data and accessors. Thanks for the suggestion.